# method does not support a request body: GET/POST

Tags: java, android, http, http-post, httprequest

Cannot send GET or POST reply request to server, getting following error

```
java.net.ProtocolException: method does not support a request body: GET/POST
```

What I try to do is to read site content and calculate a simple math equation which is being generated in there and send answer back to server. Cannot figure out why it throws exception and how to fix my issue.

```
class HTTPRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String field1;
    String field2;

    public HTTPRequest (String arg1, String arg2) {
        field1 = arg1;
        field2 = arg2;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String html = readStream(in);

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\t+(\\d+) ([+-]) (\\d+) = <input name=\"answer\"");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);

            Integer res = null;
            if (matcher.find()) {
                if (matcher.group(2).equals("-"))
                    res = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) - Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
                else if (matcher.group(2).equals("+"))
                    res = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
            }

            //Result is calculated! sending POST request
            if (res != null) {
                Log.d("RESULT", Integer.toString(res));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("field1", "UTF-8")
                        + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(field1, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("field2", "UTF-8") + "="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(field2, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("answer", "UTF-8") + "="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(res), "UTF-8");

                //ERR ON THIS LINE
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(data);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in1.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                Log.d("RESPONE",respone);

            }
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),1000);
        for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line =r.readLine()){
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        is.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

traceback:

```
System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: method does not support a request body: POST
System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:201)
System.err:     at com.streak.myapp.HTTPRequest.doInBackground(HTTPRequest.java:73)
System.err:     at com.streak.myapp.HTTPRequest.doInBackground(HTTPRequest.java:24)
System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: add `conn.setDoInput(true);` and run it again ? Could you also post the complete stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: @Blackbelt still doesn't work, stacktrace is added

Comment: are you writing the backend too? Is it possible that the backend does not support post requests?

Comment: @Blackbelt no i don't, but it does since i've done the same on python and it worked

Comment: which line is HTTPRequest.java 73 ?

Comment: @Blackbelt `DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());`

Comment: on which version of android is it happening ?

Comment: @Blackbelt my device is 5.0.2 but its also happning on android emulator on api level 18

Comment: why are you reading, writing and reading it again ?

Comment: @Blackbelt first im reading the html to get math equation and then sending answer back to server and reading the server's respone

Comment: what happens if you send a fix string. Without reading the first time. Do you get the same exception ?

Comment: @Blackbelt no it does not throw any exception... thats strange

Comment: no it is not imo. I would have expected the same behaviour. What happens if you use the old code (reading, writing, reading), and remove `is.close();` from readStream?

Comment: @Blackbelt same old behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my issue by adding

```
CookieHandler.setDefault( new CookieManager( null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL ) );
```

and creating new connection to the same host.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
    CookieHandler.setDefault( new CookieManager( null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL ) );
    String data="";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        String html = readStream(in);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\t+(\\d+) ([+-]) (\\d+) = <input name=\"answer\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);

        Integer res = null;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            if (matcher.group(2).equals("-"))
                res = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) - Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
            else if (matcher.group(2).equals("+"))
                res = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
        }

        if (res != null) {
            data += URLEncoder.encode("field1", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(field1, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("field2", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(field2, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("answer", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(res), "UTF-8");
        }
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setDoOutput(true); //ENABLE POST REQUEST
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(data);
        wr.flush(); wr.close();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        data = readStream(in);
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Now data==final html respond
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data);
    Elements allAnchorTags = doc.select("tr");
    return null;
}
```